# Apache HTTP Server, Tomcat and rewriting

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite

Scenario:

Apache reverse proxy to Tomcat:

`https://sub-domain.example.com:8080/app`

To this:

`https://sub-domain.example.com/app`

When resolving to the app, it appends like so:

`https://sub-domain.example.com/app/somedir/some.jsp`

Is there a way in the request handling process we can remove the last appendage so the end-user just sees the following:

`https://sub-domain.example.com/app`

Our current Apache configuration:

```
ServerName sub-domain.example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R]

<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/VendorCA.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/server.key
ServerName sub-domain.example.com
ServerAdmin admin@sub-domain.example.com
ErrorLog logs/sub-domain.example.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/sub-domain.example.com-access_log common
ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8080/app/
ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:8080/app/
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help will be really appreciated.